# How to use MediaMuxerTest (a AndroidTestCase file)

Tags: android, android-testing, test-suite

I find demo for MeediaMuxer, which is a AndroidTestCase File. Here is the [link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/kitkat-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/MediaMuxerTest.java).

I never used Android Test. I did some research, but most of them are somehow a little complex... It seems like that I need a xml file, a java file for TestSuite and a java file for AndroidTestCase. And now I have the AndroidTestCase, could anyone tell me how to write the TestSuite? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From [TestSuit](http://developer.android.com/reference/junit/framework/TestSuite.html#createTest%28java.lang.Class%3C?%3E,%20java.lang.String%29) overview

> A TestSuite is a Composite of Tests. It runs a collection of test
>   cases. Here is an example using the dynamic test definition.

```
 TestSuite suite= new TestSuite();
 suite.addTest(new MathTest("testAdd"));
 suite.addTest(new MathTest("testDivideByZero"));
```

Android provide a pretty good documentation for that, tell me if you have more questions after reading it.

Also [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html) is the official article about testing in Android.

Comment: Thank you Babibu! I've read the file. So I should create a new Test project with eclipse, and put the AndroidTestCase file in that project. Right?